# Duplicate identifier 'export=', Duplicate string index signature, Duplicate number index signature

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

After installing the

> jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped

I get the following errors when doing a `tsc`:

- TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export=',
- TS2374: Duplicate string index signature,
- TS2375: Duplicate number index signature

**What do they mean and how to solve them?**

I have read a dozens of threads here, but none helped.
[image]

**Virtual folder in VS2015**:
[image]

Comment: Seems like you have two definition files for jQuery. Did you try to remove the one in "typings"? Using TS 2+ the correct way adding typings is to install `@types`. You should not need to have other typings :)

Comment: Removing typings folder solved this issue, thanks. Will accept this as an answer if you provide one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have two definition files for jQuery. Did you try to remove the one in "typings"? Using TS 2+ the correct way adding typings is to install `@types`. You should not need to have other typings :)

As an alternative, you could also specify a root directory in the compiler options. [See the official documentation.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types)

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "typeRoots" : ["./typings"]
   }
}
```